# How to override getAddUrl in class Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with changing getAddUrl() method in magento. In this method:

```
public function getAddUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        $routeParams = array(
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->_getHelperInstance('core')
                ->urlEncode($this->getCurrentUrl()),
            'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );

        if (!empty($additional)) {
            $routeParams = array_merge($routeParams, $additional);
        }

        if ($product->hasUrlDataObject()) {
            $routeParams['_store'] = $product->getUrlDataObject()->getStoreId();
            $routeParams['_store_to_url'] = true;
        }

        if ($this->_getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout'
            && $this->_getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'cart') {
            $routeParams['in_cart'] = 1;
        }

        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/add', $routeParams);
    }
```

we have line:

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->_getHelperInstance('core')
                ->urlEncode($this->getCurrentUrl()),
```

I need to change the current url to another:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl()
```

But i do not know what is the proper way to do this. 
Thanks in advance for all tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way to overwrite class:

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_MagentoCommunity>
            <version>0.0.0.2</version>
        </SR_MagentoCommunity>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart>SR_MagentoCommunity_Helper_Cart</cart>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Helper/Cart.php

**Modify here as your need**

```
<?php
class SR_MagentoCommunity_Helper_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart
{
    public function getAddUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        $routeParams = array(
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->_getHelperInstance('core')
                ->urlEncode($this->getCurrentUrl()),
            'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );

        if (!empty($additional)) {
            $routeParams = array_merge($routeParams, $additional);
        }

        if ($product->hasUrlDataObject()) {
            $routeParams['_store'] = $product->getUrlDataObject()->getStoreId();
            $routeParams['_store_to_url'] = true;
        }

        if ($this->_getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout'
            && $this->_getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'cart') {
            $routeParams['in_cart'] = 1;
        }

        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/add', $routeParams);
    }
}
```

> app/etc/modules/SR_MagentoCommunity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_MagentoCommunity>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SR_MagentoCommunity>
    </modules>
</config>
```